# MicrosoftAccount Authentication with Azure MobileServices

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services, microsoft-account

I have an application that I have connected to the cloud by following different tutorials made by Azure. I however have the problem that the login feature for MicrosoftAccount gives me a token, that will as far as I can see on forums expire.

I know it is possible with Live-id, and I have a working example using Live-id. But the solution does not seem to be very nice when using it together with mobileservices.

Is there anyway to make

`user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);`

possible for the app to log in automatically, such that the token does not expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You will have to implement a HttpClientHandler and store the token in - for example - the Password Valut.

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient(
    "https://xxxxxxxx.azure-mobile.net", null, handler);
```

You can find a detailed writeup from Mike Taulty at http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2013/12/05/windows-8-1-accounts-settings-authentication-azure-mobile-services.aspx

Comment: As far as I can gather. What he has made is that he stores the token, and can retrieve it. An example of this is also shown on [azure][1]. But what I wanted was that the app can relogin the user. So even if the token has been stored and expires. Then you still will not have to use your credentials to login, this is possible with live-id, but I can't see it in the link you supplied or am I missing something?

[1]:http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-phone-get-started-users/

Comment: I do not believe this is not possible with the given architecture. A token expires after 20(?) days and afterwands the live/twitter/facebook service will have issue a new token. I am not aware of a possiblity to send the user/pass via code to renew the token. (Especially since some services started using 2 factor authentification)

Comment: Okay do you know for a fact that the token last 20 days? I thought it was much shorter?
Along site this I have liveid code that makes it possible, because you can get certain permissions that lets the app do it. BUT these permissions or extraordinary and I am afraid the user will not accept these.

But I still see it as not that user friendly that you every 20 days(?) has to relogin?